# Linux Mint is detecting mic, but mic is not picking up sound

Tags: linux-mint, microphone

So, my mic is detecting SOMETHING, but not what I'm saying into it. My mic is an Insignia NS-PAUM50.

lsusb gives me:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2322 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID a014:b014  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a2c:4b6a China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04a9:1749 Canon, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c24a Logitech, Inc. G600 Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It's not showing up on lsusb, but it is showing up on my sound input screen, oddly enough. It's also picking up SOMETHING, but it clearly isn't audio, as you can see from the video below.

https://www.youtube.com/edit?o=U&video_id=vd1MQRwQR_I

Comment: I don't know it is is related... but... I use a phone handsfree headset in my PC, and even when the sound works from the beginning, the mic doesn't. I always have to unplug and plug it again to make it start working.

Comment: Did you get this working?